# Length of perimeter of a right triangle is ‘x’ inches and the length of the altitude perpendicular to the hypotenuse is ‘y’ inches. Find the sides.

Tags: trigonometry

I would prefer the method rather than a direct solution please. I tried solving for the hypotenuse but couldn't get it in terms of x and y.

Answer (score 2):

Always start by drawing a diagram. Make sure you note which angles are right angles.

Then you'll find that the altitude of a right triangle actually makes 2 smaller triangles similar to the big triangle! Look at the diagram below (different names)

Triangle ADC is also a right triangle (angle at D) and one of the other angles (angle at C) is the same as one of the angles of ABC (also the angle at C). So triangles ADC and ABC are similar, but kinda flipped and rotated (make sure to keep good track of how the similar triangles are oriented). Similarly with triangle ABD.

[image]

Then it's a matter of setting up a bunch of equations and solving.

Comment: +1 for a strategy, not an answer, as per the OP's request.